# How to change the mode from read-write to read-only in a File-resource object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io, file-permissions

My code needs to create a file, write to it, and then change the file-bject to read-only mode.

What I do now, seems kindof ugly: I open the file with mode "wb", write to it, close it, then re-open it with mode "rb":

```
open(@cached_file_name, 'wb') { |file| file.write("foo") }    
@cached_file = open(@cached_file_name, 'rb')
```

Is it possible to change the file from "wb" to "rb" without opening and closing it? Like:

```
@cached_file = open(@cached_file_name, 'wb')
@cached_file.write("foo")
@cached_file.mode= 'r'
```

I am not aware of such a `mode=` method though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm not aware of a way to do that, and I think that stems from the `open` syscall in Linux which can't do that.

The [RubyDoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000889) for `IO.new` states:

> When the mode of original IO is read only, the mode cannot be changed to be writable. Similarly, the mode cannot be changed from write only to readable. If such a wrong change is directed, timing where the error actually occurs is different according to the platform.

But I note that that doesn't explicity state what you can or can't do for read/write modes...